# Using the Borel-Cantelli lemmas

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am really struggling to understand this question any advice would be appreciated.

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables, each with the exponential distribution with rate $1/2$.

a) Use the Borel-Cantelli lemmas to show that

$$P(X_n > \alpha \log n\text{ for infinitely many }n) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad& \text{if}    \:\:\:\alpha > 2  \\    1 & \text{if} \:\:\:  \alpha \le  2  \\ \end{cases}$$

b) Show that $\limsup_n \dfrac{Xn}{\log n} = 2$ almost surely.

Hint: Consider the events $\{X_n > 2 \log n \:\: \text{i.o.}\}$ and $\{X_n > (2 + 2/k) \log n \:\: \text{i.o.}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

Note $P(X_n > \alpha \log n) = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha/2}}$. What can you say about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n > \alpha\log n)$ for different values of $\alpha$?

Hint: For $\alpha>2$ apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma. For $\alpha \le 2$, apply the "converse" Borel-Cantelli lemma.

b)

By part a), $P\{X_n > 2 \log n \text{ i.o.}\}=1$, so, $\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} \ge 2$ almost surely.

If we show $\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} \le 2$ almost surely, or equivalently $P\left\{\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2\right\}=0$, then we are finished.

For any $k>0$ we have
$$P\left\{\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2+2/k\right\}
\le P\{X_n >(2+2/k)\log n \text{ i.o.}\} = 0$$
using part a) again.
Taking $k \to \infty$ and noting $\left\{\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2+2/k\right\}$ is an increasing sequence of sets gives
$$P\left\{\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2\right\} = 0.$$

Comment: I came across this proof, and I have a quick question on that. How do we relate the $\lim\sup$ of a sequence of events to $\lim\sup$ of a sequence of random variables? Specifically, could you please clarify why $P(X_n > 2\log n \text{ i.o.}) =1 \iff P(\lim\sup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n}\ge2)=1$. I do not understand why you changed the inequality $\ge$ to the strict inequality $>$. Any response or comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Arthur I only needed the implication "$\implies$"; I don't think the converse holds. The implication really does not involve random variables at all; it suffices to show "$\frac{x_n}{\log n}> 2$ i.o." implies "$\limsup \frac{x_n}{\log n} \ge 2$" for a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)$. This follows almost immediately from the definition of $\limsup$: $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{\log n} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge m} \frac{x_n}{\log n} \ge \lim_{m \to \infty} 2 = 2.$ The inequality becomes non-strict because in general you can have two sequences $a_n > b_n$ with the same limit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have one more question, related to the same issue. In the proof, you claimed 
$$P\left\{\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2+2/k\right\}
\le P\{X_n >(2+2/k)\log n \text{ i.o.}\}. $$ Could you please explain why there is "$\le$" between these two probabilities. Shouldn't these two probabilities be equal (according to the definition of "$A_n$ i.o." which is equivalent to the $\lim\sup A_n$, for some event $A_n$)? I greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: @Arthur This is the same as my previous comment: the event on the right-hand side "$\frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2 + 2/k \text{ i.o.}$" does not imply the event on the left-hand side "$\limsup \frac{X_n}{\log n} > 2 + 2/k$" because of the possible case of equality in the limsup.

Comment: Thank you very much @angryavian. That's a subtle point!

Answer (score 1):

b)

First show that  ${\sf P} (\lim \sup_n \frac{X_n}{\ln n} \ge 2) = 1 $:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-(1-\varepsilon/2)} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {\sf P} (X_n > (2-\varepsilon)\ln n) = \infty$. Now, using BKL we have:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {\sf P} (X_n > (2-\varepsilon)\ln n) = \infty \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0 {\sf P} (\frac{X_n}{\ln n} > 2 - \varepsilon \text{ i. m.} ) = 1 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0 \:\:{\sf P} (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\:\: \exists m > n: \frac{X_m}{\ln m} > 2 - \varepsilon ) = 1  \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow {\sf P}(\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \:\:\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\:\: \exists m > n: \frac{X_m}{\ln m} > 2 - \frac{1}{k}) = 1 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow {\sf P} (\forall \varepsilon > 0\:\:\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\:\: \exists m > n: \frac{X_m}{\ln m} > 2 - \varepsilon) = 1 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow P(\lim \sup_n \frac{X_n}{\ln n} \ge 2 ) = 1$$

Now, similar to this, show that ${\sf P} (\lim \sup_n \frac{X_n}{\ln n} \le 2) = 1 $.
These inequalities together imply what you want.

Comment: here $\mathbb P(X_n>\alpha \log (n))\le \frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}$