# Borel-Cantelli lemmas

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables, each with the exponential distribution with rate $1/2$.

a) Use the Borel-Cantelli lemmas to show that

$$P(X_n> \alpha \log(n) \text{for infinitely many $n$}) =\begin{cases}0 & \alpha>2 \\1 & \alpha \leq 2 \end{cases}$$

I found the answer and the question in this link but I did not understand
[Using the Borel-Cantelli lemmas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038390/using-the-borel-cantelli-lemmas)

Comment: Tell us which steps in the proof you couldn't understand.

Comment: i got that P\left(Xn > alpha log n )= n power ( -alph/2)

Answer (score 2):

$X_n$ are iid $Exp(1/2)$ so $P(X_n>x) = e^{-x/2}$.

For $a > 2$ case, consider $P(X_n > (2+\epsilon)\log n)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Thus $P(X_n > (2+\epsilon)\log n) = \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon/2}}$. Therefore, when summing over all $n$, $\sum P(X_n > (2+\epsilon)\log n) = \sum \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon/2}} < \infty$ is a convergent sum (if you don't understand this, review harmonic series). Therefore, by Borel-Cantelli, $P(X_n > (2+\epsilon)\log n \text{ i.o.}) = 0$.

You can argue analogously for when $a \leq 2$.